# Format shiny DT column filter end range values to match formatPercentage

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a shiny datatable with some columns formatted as percentages, but the min/max values in the range sliders for these columns do not update with this formatting. How can I alter the range slider values format to match the percent formatting in all percent columns?

[Shiny datatable with circled column range slider values and formatted column values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNKmC.png)

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput('iris')
)

server = function(input, output) {
  
  df <- iris %>% dplyr::filter(Species == "setosa")
  
  output$iris <-  DT::renderDT({
    datatable(df, filter="top") %>% 
      formatPercentage(2:3, digits=1)
  })     
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I don't think percent can be interpreted as number, then cannot be a range slider. There is a workaround like this df$Sepal.Width = df$Sepal.Width*100 without "%".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of DT v0.32 this will "just work". You can try it out with the development version:

```r
pak::pak("rstudio/DT")
```

[image]